# Single .jks Files contain multiple key-store for SAML application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-saml, spring-security-saml2

My application need to connect to multiple Idp Providers using SAML, for this I have generated multiple .jks files with key-alias and Password of their own , but I need a single .jks file containing all them. is there any way to merge these , I have tried KeyStore -import but its not working
I am using Spring Security SAML extension in application and it need a Single key-manager object pointing to single .jks file

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a TrustStore.

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias rootCert1 -file cert_1_location -keystore trusted-keystore.p12 -storetype pkcs12
```

Likewise, you can import another certificate in the same TrustStore:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias rootCert2 -file cert_2_location -keystore trusted-keystore.p12 -storetype pkcs12
```